# Do you know how to set "weak" initial values to each of z3 Array element?

Tags: z3

For example, is there a something like below weak_Store function in Z3?

```
from z3 import * 

a = Array('a', IntSort(), IntSort()) 
a = weak_Store(a, 0, 0) 
a = weak_Store(a, 1, 1) 


s = Solver() 
s.add(a[0] == 100) 
print(s.check()) # should print "sat"

print(s.model().eval(a[0]))  # should print "100"
print(s.model().eval(a[1]))  # should print "1" which is stored as weak_Store.
```

**Since a[1] is not involved in the above constraint solving, this should not be computed and changed even after s.check().**

I think this is related to `model_completion` variable in `z3_model_eval`,
but `z3_model_eval` does not work for z3 `Array` element.
Although the example is written in Python, I would like to do it with z3 C api.

Can anybody help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of constraints are called "soft" constraints, i.e., those that can be violated if necessary, but the solver will try to satisfy them otherwise. Note that you have to use the `Optimize` object, (not `Solver`), which has diminished capacity in general. (i.e., slower, more likely to say `unknown` etc.)

To add a soft constraint, use `add_soft` instead of `add` in z3py. You can code your example in Python like this:

```py
from z3 import *

a = Array('a', IntSort(), IntSort())

s = Optimize()

s.add_soft(a[0] == 0)
s.add_soft(a[1] == 1)

s.add(a[0] == 100)
print(s.check())

print(s.model().eval(a[0]))
print(s.model().eval(a[1]))
```

This prints:

```
sat
100
1
```

as you requested.

In the C-API, the corresponding call is [Z3_optimize_assert_soft](https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/group__capi.html#ga4fec5d5997cd90dcc01cd3cddae73915).

Comment: I guess Optimize object of SMT solver also attempts to find solutions of the objects involved in soft constraints in addition to hard(normal) constraints. However I guess I can do that without computations of those unnecessary ones because I just want to set **initial** values of all elements of Array object. Do you know any alternatives?

Comment: I'm not aware of any other method. In an industrial setting, you'd first run your regular SAT solver. Once you get a model, you'd add these soft-constraints on a subset of input variables to get a "quieter" model, i.e., one that has less noise. That way, the first SAT call can share its learned lemmas with the second call, and speed up the process. (And typically, `unsat` would be the expectation anyhow.) Z3's optimizing solver (also known as MaxSAT/MaxSMT) solver does not implement this architecture, as far as I know. In an industrial tool, you wouldn't want the slow MaxSAT to execute first.